# Get the coordinates of visible part of screen when zoomed in

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I'm using a [custom lib](https://natario1.github.io/ZoomLayout/docs/zoom-engine) that implements a zoomable, pinchable and scrollable layout, but I when I zoom the layout in, I cant get the coordinates of the visible part. Is there a way of doing that? Android documentation explains nothing about viewport.

This pictures has an example. The rectangle in the left is my layout. When I zoom it, the user will only see the smaller one, but it will fill all the screen. How can I get the coordinates of the small rectangle (in red)?

[image]

Comment: You mean *Window* rather than *Viewport* about "the visible part"? For I think Viewport is ImageView itself.

Comment: @hata I mean the visible part of the layout. As it's zoomed in, user is not seeing all of it. Android documentation calls the "windows" of visible content as viewport: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll?hl=pt-br

But It's not an imageview, it's a zoomable layout.

Comment: Ok, I see. Exactly saying, to my humble knowledge, the visible part on the device is called *Viewport* while that on the source image is called *Window*. But now I see what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not [the library](https://natario1.github.io/ZoomLayout/home)'s true user that I don't know actual answer. But I myself do similar thing as the library in my custom ImageView. So I can suggest somewhat. Please try and examine later by yourself.

The library has those [Pan APIs](https://natario1.github.io/ZoomLayout/docs/pan-apis). I think by using either `getPan()`/`getPanX()`/`getPanY()` or `getScaledPan()`/`getScaledPanX()`/`getScaledPanY()` you can get the left-top point's coordinates. (Maybe, the latter *scaled* ones are what you want?)

Once you get the left-top point's coordinates, you can calculate the others by the rectangle's width and height.

To know width and height, you can reverse-calculate from your ImageView's width and height, and current scale factor.

To know the width and height of your ImageView, use [`getWidth()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getWidth()) and [`getHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getHeight()).

To know the current scale factor of the library, either `getZoom()` or `getRealZoom()` of [Zoom APIs](https://natario1.github.io/ZoomLayout/docs/zoom-apis) should be usable.

Then, divide ImageView's width or height by the current scale factor and you get the rectangle's width or height.

At last, based on the left-top point's coordinates, left-bottom point is plus height, right-top point is plus width and right-bottom point is plus width and height.

---

**Sample Code**

layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.otaliastudios.zoom.ZoomImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoomImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:alignment="top|left"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:maxZoom="2"
        app:maxZoomType="zoom"
        app:minZoom="0.5"
        app:minZoomType="zoom"
        app:overPinchable="false"
        app:overScrollHorizontal="false"
        app:overScrollVertical="false"
        app:threeFingersScrollEnabled="false"
        app:transformation="centerCrop"
        app:transformationGravity="top|left"
        app:twoFingersScrollEnabled="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/zoomImageView">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.otaliastudios.zoom.ZoomImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ZoomImageView zoomImageView;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        zoomImageView = findViewById(R.id.zoomImageView);
        zoomImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2880x2880, null));
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        textView.setText(String.format(
                "pan (on the World (src image) coordinates):\n\t%s\n" +
                        "scaledPan (on the Display coordinates):\n\t%s\n" +
                        "zoom (relative ratio to the initial scale):\n\t%f\n" +
                        "realZoom (real scale factor for the image):\n\t%f\n" +
                        "the View's layout width: %d\n" +
                        "the View's layout height: %d\n\n" +
                        "the Window rect: (%f, %f) - (%f, %f)",
                zoomImageView.getPan().toString(),
                zoomImageView.getScaledPan().toString(),
                zoomImageView.getZoom(),
                zoomImageView.getRealZoom(),
                zoomImageView.getWidth(),
                zoomImageView.getHeight(),
                -zoomImageView.getPanX(),
                -zoomImageView.getPanY(),
                -zoomImageView.getPanX() + ((float) zoomImageView.getWidth()) / zoomImageView.getRealZoom(),
                -zoomImageView.getPanY() + ((float) zoomImageView.getHeight()) / zoomImageView.getRealZoom()
        ));
    }
}
```

And `drawable-nodpi/img2880x2880.png`. So my test device's display width is 1440px that I prepared a square image of 2880px by 2880px with checker 1440px squares.

You can pan (scroll) the image and pinch zoom-in/out it. When you push the button, it indicates current status. Of the last, *Window rect* should be what you want.

Note that because

```
-zoomImageView.getPanX() + ((float) zoomImageView.getWidth()) / zoomImageView.getRealZoom()
```

or

```
-zoomImageView.getPanY() + ((float) zoomImageView.getHeight()) / zoomImageView.getRealZoom()
```

is a calculation of float values, the result value may partially contain calculation error.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried it like that: `rectangle.x = -1 * layout.engine.panX) + (layout.width/5f)/2f` (the value is negative, so I just multiplied by -1). I divided by 5f because that's my scale, and 2f because I wanted the center position, but  my imageview isn't centered. I used random values like `rectangle.x = -1 * layout.engine.panX) + (layout.width/5f * 0.213f), just tried random values until my imageview get centered. It worked on my phone, but running on AVD and testing on another screens, it didn't work.

Comment: That's weird because I centered a TextView based on another imageview position trying random values and it worked in different screens, like that: `actionText.x = star.position.x - dpToPx(26).toFloat()`. But it didn't work with the rectangle (a simple imageview that I made with XML). The "star" is a imageview that was already in the layout before the zoom, so when te user touches it, the layout zooms as moves to the star in a way the star will be centered, so I based the TextView position in this star and it worked.

Comment: @LucasRodrigues I made a sample code using `ZoomImageView` class.

Comment: Thanks! I made it like that: `rectangle.y = (-layout.engine.panY + view.height/layout.zoom) - rectangle.height` and it's correctly positioned in different screens :).